# VS2010 Report Viewer control does not showing tooltip

Tags: reporting-services, tooltip

I have a report that displays an image in a matrix report's table column. The image has a tooltip associated with it. When I view the report in Report Manager it displays the tooltip. When I display the report in a ReportViewer control (in remote mode pointing at the same report) the tooltip does not display.

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? What did your research come up with? Can you be more specific about your situation, help us with an [sscce](http://sscce)?

Comment: I am showing report in my web application using asp.net report viewer control, while display I am not able to see tooltip associated with matrix. but if I open the same report with Report server URL we can see all tooltips very easily.